# Filter Left join sql

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have this sql query :

```
SELECT Customer.IDCustomer, Customer.Name,
Sign.IdSign, Sign.Name, Sign.Delete
FROM Customer
LEFT JOIN  Sign_Customer ON Sign_Customer.IDCustomer=Customer.IDCustomer 
     AND  ( SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN S_C.Delete=0 OR S_C.Delete is Null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT )
            FROM Sign AS S_C
            WHERE S_C.IdSign=Sign_Customer.IdSign)=1
LEFT JOIN Sign ON Sign.IdSign=Sign_Customer.IdSign

ORDER BY Customer.Name
```

This query works fine, but I want to know if it exists another way to filter my first left join without use the SELECT CAST... condition.

---

### Update

Sorry, I don't explain what I want in my result:

- All my customer without Sign
- All my customer whith enable Sign

A Customer with disable Sign doesn't appear or appear like a "without Sign" if no enable Sign exist for it.

Exemple:
my customer table

```
IDCustomer   | Name
1            | Customer 1
2            | Customer 2
3            | Customer 3
4            | Customer 4
```

Sign_Customer:

```
IDCustomer   | IdSign
1            | 1
3            | 2
3            | 3
3            | 5
4            | 4
```

Sign

```
IdSign       | Name         | Delete
1            | Sign1        | 0
2            | Sign2        | 1
3            | Sign3        | 0
4            | Sign4        | 1
5            | Sign5        | 0
```

Result

```
Customer.IDCustomer | Customer.Name  | Sign.IdSign | Sign.Name | Sign.Delete
1                   | Customer 1     | 1           | Sign1     | 0
2                   | Customer 2     | null        | null      | null
3                   | Customer 3     | 3           | Sign3     | 0
3                   | Customer 3     | 5           | Sign5     | 0
4                   | Customer 4     | null        | null      | null
```

Comment: Is this result for IDCustomer=4 correct?

Comment: yes, because I make my test on the Sign_Customer Left join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following?

```
   SELECT Customer.IDCustomer
        , Customer.Name
        , Sign.IdSign
        , Sign.Name
        , Sign.Delete
     FROM Customer
LEFT JOIN Sign_Customer
     JOIN Sign
       ON Sign_Customer.IdSign = Sign.IdSign
      AND Sign.Delete = 0
       ON Customer.IDCustomer = Sign_Customer.IDCustomer
 ORDER BY Customer.NAME;
```

Comment: As a bit of an explanation; Sign and Sign_Customer  are joined where Sign.Delete is 0. The resultset is then LEFT JOINed to Customer. This behaviour is controlled by the position of the ON Customer.IDCustomer = Sign_Customer.IDCustomer statement, which encompasses the Sign and Sign_Customer JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Customer.IDCustomer, Customer.Name, Sign.IdSign, Sign.LibEnseigne, Sign.Delete
FROM Customer
LEFT JOIN  Sign_Customer ON Sign_Customer.IDCustomer=Customer.IDCustomer 
LEFT JOIN Sign ON Sign.IdSign=Sign_Customer.IdSign
AND (S_C.Delete=0 OR S_C.Delete is Null)
ORDER BY TEnseigne.NomEnseigne, Customer.Name
```

Comment: It was my first idea, but it don't work. The rows with delete Signs appear in the result and the Sign name is empty.

Comment: CAN YOU PROVIDE DATA FOR THIS WITH EXPECTED RESULT?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this meets your criteria:

```
SELECT Customer.IDCustomer, Customer.Name,
Sign.IdSign, Sign.Name, Sign.Delete
FROM Customer
LEFT JOIN (
  select Sign_Customer.*
  from Sign_Customer
  join Sign on S_C.IdSign=Sign_Customer.IdSign
  where isnull(S_C.Delete,0) = 0
) Sign_Customer ON Sign_Customer.IDCustomer=Customer.IDCustomer 
LEFT JOIN Sign ON Sign.IdSign=Sign_Customer.IdSign    
ORDER BY Customer.Name
```